# SharePoint List form buttons and &Source on Cancel and Close

Tags: list, css, custom, user-controls, postback

If I don't SharePoint Designer customize List  newform, editform and dispforms, can I still use my own button outside of the webpart to submit data from the form. Say I'm using CSS to hide the generated buttons.. i can do that. but can I add a sharePoint button to submit? I tried adding this one to a newform, but it does not work.

```
<div class="x" style="width:80px">
<SharePoint:savebutton CssClass="x"  runat="server" ControlMode="Edit" id="savebutton1" Text="SUBMIT"/>
</div>
```

Also, Say I can live with generated buttons above and blow the form and cancel and close buttons.  And say I want my form to redirect via query string &Source=... do my cancel and close buttons have to redirect to the same place as the OK button??

Again, I'm **NOT** looking to customize forms in SharePoint designer, I'd like to work with what SharePoint generates if at all possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually via SharePoint designer you could start by insert a new "Custom form" (next to Data View on the Insert tab) for the list targetted. Actually there is no need to customize any of the forms, you could do this on any WIki/WebPart page.

As a result you would get the default Insert view, of course, however you could start doing whatever you want with that, including hiding fields, remove/add custom buttons. Starting from this point add you own button via the Toolbox using Submit button. Change accordingly Value for a different label and using ddwrt:GenFireServerEvent function to chain multiple actions.

Use this article for an example as the Button actions plus Parameters could give you quite some flexibility http://blogs.technet.com/b/brenclarke/archive/2009/04/14/creating-a-quiz-web-application-using-sharepoint-designer-part-4.aspx

Comment: It's crazy, but I forgot about this and that I could set my ID query string. Thanks.

Comment: Not sure why, but trying to use my own query string variable for ListItemID and no listitem data renders, just blank. Do I need a connection webpart to use my own query string variable beyond setting in dataview webparts?

Comment: This is weird, the form works great with my own query string, but stops working if I remove the close buttons.  I have to set them to visible=false instead anyways.

Comment: I'm find the custom List form on a folder outside of the list folder to be completely flaky.. at least for this list. I may have a problem with the list. It works, then then stops working and displays nothing again. the only thing different with this list is that has version history.